# How to graph an absolute value equation?

Tags: graphing-functions, absolute-value

How would you graph:

$|x+y|=1$ ?
I  can do the normal $y=|x+1|$ and all that. But how would you do a question with two of these unknowns in the absolute value?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem as though $|x+y|=1$ is a function, since for $x=2$, the values $y=-1$ and $y=-3$ both satisfy the equation. 
The way to graph this would be to graph two individual equations: $x+y=1$ and $x+y=-1$ (these two equations result when we lift the absolute value). So we graph separately:
$$y=-x+1$$$$y=-x-1$$

Comment: Just changed the "function" to "equation"

Comment: But do you know how to do these?

Comment: @missiledragon "But how would you do a question with two of these unknowns in the absolute value?" Perhaps if you could print the question I would be more able to help.

Comment: What do you mean? It asks to sketch the graph: |x+y|=1

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cx%2By%7C%3D1&lk=4&num=2 also, read my edit (I explained how to graph the equation)

Comment: *But* [how] *do you know how to do these?* Since "$|u| = 1$" is equivalent to "$u = -1$ or $u = 1$", the graph of $|u| = 1$ is the union of the graph of $u = -1$ and the graph of $u = 1.$ In your case, the graph of $|x+y|=1$ is the union of the graph of $x+y=1$ (i.e. the line $y=-x+1$) and the graph of $x+y=-1$ (i.e. the line $y=-x-1$).